# Laravel DomPDF Unable to Create Multiple PDF

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have two data and I will make one data for each pdf. but the output that I produce is one pdf and only the first loop data is displayed. is there something wrong? thank you

```
public function emailPdf(Request $request){

        DB::beginTransaction();
        // $autocrm_class = new CRM;

        $post = $request->all();

        $post['id_brand'] = 1;
        $post['date_today'] = "2020-02-07";

        // $post['date_today'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post['date_today']));

        $data = BrandOutlet::where('id_brand', $post['id_brand'])->with('brandOutletDelivery.brandOutletTujuan');
        $data->with(["brandOutletDelivery.brandOutletDeliveryItems" => function($q) use($post){
            $q->whereDate('created_at', '=', $post['date_today'])->with('brandItem')->with('unit');
        }]);

        $data->with(["brandOutletOpnamePagi.brandOutletOpnameItems" => function($q) use($post){
            $q->whereDate('created_at', [$post['date_today']])->with('brandItem')->with('unit');

        }]);

        $data->with(["brandOutletOpnameMalam.brandOutletOpnameItems" => function($q) use($post){
            $q->whereDate('created_at', [$post['date_today']])->with('brandItem')->with('unit');

        }]);


        $data = $data->get();

            $html = '';
            foreach($data as $result){
                $view = view('pdf.delivery', ['result' => $result]);
                $html .= $view->render();
            }

            // return $html //I tried to debug by displaying it in View and the result is 2 data
            $pdf = \PDF::loadHtml($html);
            $sheet = $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            $pdf->save('pdf/'.$result['id'].'.pdf');
            return $sheet->stream();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $html = [];
        foreach($data as $i=>$result){
            $view = view('pdf.delivery', ['result' => $result]);
            $html[$i]= $view->render();
        }



foreach($html as $htm){
        $pdf = \PDF::loadHtml($htm);
        $sheet = $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
        $pdf->save('pdf/'.$result['id'].'.pdf');
        return $sheet->stream();
```

}

please try this

Comment: Does not have any effect, just changes to the loop to other data

Comment: and also data in PDF blank (only header in PDF is displayed)

Comment: sorry i miss understand u

Comment: solve it by this code 
foreach($data as $i=>$result){
$view = view('pdf.delivery', ['result' => $result]);
 $html[$i] = $view->render();
}

Comment: I have tried the method above. but there isn't any effect.  
Sorry if my language can't be understood

Comment: and foreach  on html Array  when load PDF

Comment: $html = [];
            foreach($data as $i=>$result){
                $view = view('pdf.delivery', ['result' => $result]);
                $html[$i]= $view->render();
            }

            // return $html //I tried to debug by displaying it in View and the result is 2 data
foreach($html as $htm){
            $pdf = \PDF::loadHtml($htm);
            $sheet = $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            $pdf->save('pdf/'.$result['id'].'.pdf');
            return $sheet->stream();
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207488/discussion-between-mustafa-goda-and-khaiz-badaru-tammam).

Comment: Continue in chat bro